# Wiring an advancer to an ignition coil

Tags: honda, electrical, starting, timing, vintage

An image for reference:

[image]

Ignition Coil Leftmost (1 pin)

Advancer second from left (1 pin)

Gearbox second from right (4 pin)

Battery Rightmost (4 pin, Positive, negative and a loopback)

I have just confirmed that the ignition coil works, Now I am trying to figure out if the advancer does as well before I tackle the proper wiring harness.

I figured the easiest way to do this would be to get the spark plug to light by kicking the starter over.

So how would I wire this to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking the only way to see if the advancer is working is by using an oscilloscope.

Comment: Connect it back up as it should be and test it that way - if the coil has been tested and is working and you only effectively add the advancer and it stops working then the only item that can be faulty is the advancer...

Comment: @Solar Mike 'Conecting it as it should be' is what I am trying to work out

Comment: Did you take pictures as you took it apart?

Comment: I got it in parts, so no.

Comment: This may help : https://advrider.com/index.php?threads/honda-xl-troubleshooting-spark-issues.427583/

Comment: It actually really did, I tested both the Alternator and advance with leds I had laying around and the current generated blew both leds, so I believe the coil is the problem