# Ignition Coil Not Working With Points/Stator Current

Tags: honda, motorcycle, starting, ignition-coil, vintage

I have an Ignition Coil connected to a points and the motors stator. I have tested both with leds and the power generated by kicking the motor over blew both, the stator produced a solid light and the points a flashing light. However the coil does not spark when I kick the engine over, but it does if I scrape a 6v positive lead on its protruding wire.

Is there something I could be missing or do I just need a new coil?

Comment: see this question and think about all you have been told : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/55583/10976

Comment: Not helpful, I have isolated and successfully tested each element of the system yet the system does not function. So I feel my question is appropriate.

Comment: If the coil works when it is not connected to the engine and works when you had it connected to the battery then is must be something you are not doing or have not looked at or checked or connected correctly - which is why I said "think about all you have been told". The next option that you should consider is taking it to a professional - I always enjoyed the "Monday morning" jobs - things messed up by amateurs over the weekend....

Comment: ok then, ill ask elsewhere